# responsive screen, when I minimize from full screen my right column goes to the bottom. How do I fix this?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I think I know why as soon as I release the screen from full-screen mode my right column goes to the bottom. I'm using Bootstrap and played around with the width as well. currently I have

```
<div class="col-sm-2">
<div class="col-sm-7">
<div class="col-sm-3">
```

and in css:

```
.col-sm-2 {
  width:180px;
  padding:13px 22px;
}

.col-sm-7 {
  background-color: #FFFFFF;

  width:970px;
  padding:13px 22px;
}
```

I want my `col-sm-3` to stay still even if I'm not in full screen in my desktop. Also in mobile version, if it's possible I want only `col-sm-7` to be shown in the middle. And rest of them to be way at the bottom or at the dropbox. Can someone please help me?

Comment: If you're using bootstrap, why are you giving fixed width and padding, that too in pixels?

Comment: @SatejS I still wanted to modify them, bootstrap width wasn't doing what I wanted. I put code on top of bootstrap provided

Comment: If you are using bootstrap then never use pixels for width. And when the screen is minimized your right column goes to bottom as it is pushed by the other columns. As you have mentioned widths for only small devices  col-sm (FYI which is carried forward for medium and large devices too). You must add a col-xs classes too. And I see that's already being answered its better you take some time and get yourself familiar with bootstrap documentation, do's and dont's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should define (or redefine) the width for extra small device too..

```
 <div class="col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
 <div class="col-sm-7 col-xs-7">
 <div class="col-sm-3 col-xs-3">
```

and for col-xs-? provide the related width ..

Comment: nah this doesn't work...unless I did it wrong. I added col-xs stuff like you provided

Comment: What mean doesn't work .. you get an error.? .. you don't get the result you need..? .. have you setted proper value for col-xs-2, col-xs-7, col-xs-3 width .similar at what you did for col-sm-2,-7,-3 ?

Comment: I just added xs stuff next to what I already had, it doesn't have any affect. When I cancel full screen the right sided column still goes under

Comment: Show the wdth  you assigned to the right sided column (col-3) and show the value you assigned to the class col-xs-2, col-xs-7, col-xs3. If you don't have asigned value to these they have again the default bootstrap value and this could be in contrast with you need ..

Comment: I think it's not a good idea to modify width when using bootstrap....decided to erase what I had in  cs

Comment: I don't uderstand .. you are using boostrap standard ? or you have modified the related behavior  .. (eg: changing width) with your styling? ...

Comment: This must fix your issue, unless you have added some width or other css being applied. Start a empty page put this code have only background colors to your divs without any other content and see how it behaves on screen size change.